# Get MvxListItem index when clicked

Tags: mvvm, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have an MvxListview and I need to retrieve the index value of the item that is clicked so that I may pass it on into the oncoming ViewModel.

**Is there an Mvvmcross specific solution to this? Is there a Data bind to retrieve the Index?**

The initial MvxListview is generated from a remote server using the following layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/Flashcards.Android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Mvx.MvxListview
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       local:MvxBind="ItemsSource TableData;ItemClick NavigateToItemCommand"
       local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/stackstable_item" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the navigate command.

```
//Defined in Constructor
m_navigateToItemCommand = new MvxCommand(NavigateToItem);
...

public ICommand NavigateToItemCommand
{
    get { return m_navigateToItemCommand; }
}
void NavigateToItem()
{
    //TODO Retrieve ListView Index, Pass Index to new ViewModel.
    ShowViewModel<StacksTableItemViewModel>(new
    {
    SelectedStackIndex = 0;
    });
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `MvxCommand`, you can use `MvxCommand<T>` with an `ItemClick` on an `MvxListView`

This will pass you the item back:

```
    private Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxCommand<StacksTableItem> _itemSelectedCommand;
    public System.Windows.Input.ICommand ItemSelectedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            _itemSelectedCommand = _itemSelectedCommand ?? new Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxCommand<StacksTableItem>(DoSelectItem);
            return _itemSelectedCommand;
        }
    }

    private void DoSelectItem(StacksTableItem item)
    {
        ShowViewModel<StacksTableItemViewModel>(new { id = item.Id });
    }
```

If it helps, there are a few examples of this in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/ - e.g. [inside Daily Dilbert ListViewModel.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/DailyDilbert/DailyDilbert.Core/ViewModels/ListViewModel.cs#L54)